# How to grep for staged Objective-c/++ files in Bash with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to create a git pre-commit hook for formatting (using clang-format) Objective-C and Objective-C++ files.

Let's say I've staged:

```
MyProject/Classes/App/AppDelegate.m
MyProject/Classes/Util/MPAnalytics.h
MyProject/Classes/Util/MPAnalytics.m
MyProject/Classes/Util/MPData.mm
MyProject/build/iOS/MyClass/Configs/My_Project.xcconfig
MyProject/stuff/some_file.json
```

```
#!bin/bash

declare objc_extensions="^.*\.(h|m|mm)$"
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR | grep "$objc_extensions"

# No result
```

```
$ git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR # without the regex
```

returns

```
MyProject/Classes/App/AppDelegate.m
MyProject/Classes/Util/MPAnalytics.h
MyProject/Classes/Util/MPAnalytics.m
MyProject/Classes/Util/MPData.mm
MyProject/build/iOS/MyClass/Configs/My_Project.xcconfig
MyProject/stuff/some_file.json
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try `grep -E` ?

Comment: You need to use Extended RE to use `()` in the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot `-E`

This works

```
#!bin/bash

declare objc_extensions="^.*\.(h|m|mm)$"
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR | grep -E "$objc_extensions"
```